# Is this good/bad architecture: Multiple WCF services communicating with one another through a single static object?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, architecture

A little background on myself: I've generally worked on small projects that did not require significant architecture or concerns for scaling (such as developing small scale web applications using Web Forms and MVC).

What I'm working on: I'm now building a set of WCF applications (a WCF service that routes messages between a "requester" client and a "responder" client) that needs to be stable, scalable, and obviously responsive.

What I'm doing: I have a "broker service" running two end-points, one for the requester clients and one for the responder clients. Each service and client is essentially running with WCF default values, aside from the ConcurrencyMode being set to Reentrant.

```
//Client
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]

//Service
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
```

Naturally, each service instance (PerSession) is independent from one another and can't communicate with each other. So, to build a bridge between them I have a class called MessageBroker with singleton instance that the Services access. The broker routes requests from the requester service on to the responder service, and routes responses back in the same manner.

My concern is having this one object/instance route all messages for the whole system and the performance impact of that. Right now the clients are each calling their respective Send* methods using the predefined *Async methods defined when I added the service reference, and the callbacks on the clients are firing events using the Begin/End invoke methods of the event delegate. Aside from that, for now, all the methods are called synchronously. I'm thinking of adding more multithreading in the form of using the Begin/End invoke methods of a delegate in broker (I have another question about running out of threads in the threadpool using this method).

Since I'm new to this whole design/architecture concept, I want to know if what I'm doing is the right path to be taking or if I should be considering implementing a different architecture (this is the first, and seemingly the most obvious, I have come up with).

I don't really have a mentor to bounce ideas off locally, so I hope the community can provide a little guidance.

Thanks for any advice, suggestions or criticism. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your service to scale you'll need to make the link between the participants loosely coupled. This means asynchronous queued messaging. There are countless reasons why this is a must, primarily though it would be in order to:

- survive spikes in the load
- scale-out instead of scale-up
- manage service availability downtimes (both at your end and at the service client's end)

WCF has support for queued messaging via MSMQ, but you'll have to forget pretty much *everything* about your HTTP based service model and start from scratchs with a message based paradigm. Also, you'll need to solve the problem of authenticating and routing to/from MSMQ queues deployed on your client locations (not a trivial problem by any stretch).

You could also consider a service to provide the messaging infrastructure, like [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).

And finally, if your back-end is SQL Server based end-to-end then you can use asynchrnous messaging straight from the database: [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is exactly what BizTalk was built to solve.  You might investigate either bringing it in or mimic'ing its behavior.

In a nutshell it works by doing the following:
1. message comes in from the requestor.
2. it saves the message to a database.
3. it processes the message by routing it to the appropriate destinations. (has capability to transform the message along the way).
4. it saves the message state again.
4. when the destination responds, it saves the result and forwards it to the requestor.

Basically, instead of a singleton, Biztalk maintains state by leveraging a database backend to store exactly where the message is.  Consider it like a state machine.  In the event biztalk get's rebooted or looses connectivity somewhere, it can easily get back to exactly where it was in the message pipeline.  Any thread can therefore handle any of the changes to message state; which makes it pretty robust.

The above is a *very* simplified version of what Biztalk does.  Also, there are other messaging systems that have similar behavior.  You might want to do some research before diving in to build your own solution.  Personally, I think Biztalk is rather expensive.  But my experience has been that it is rock solid and costs a lot less than having a developer (or a team) try and mimic it's functionality.

Comment: Cost is part of our motivation, the other being deployability. We will have three parts: the broker service; which will be hosted on a managed server, the requester clients; which will be a web site, a phone application, or a desktop application accessing the service, and the responder clients; a wcf client that sits on a client's network and gives us a bridge to their data to our central server so they can access their data from a central website, rather than installing clients on every machine that need access to the data. That third part was my main motivation for choosing WCF.

Comment: It sounds like I could either leverage using a database to store "messages" (requests and responses) or the windows message queue itself (I have the impression it's difficult to manage, but I could be wrong). I will investigate BizTalk as you suggested, but I'm thinking the key part of our system, the "insider" responder client, won't be cheap (maybe not easy either) with BizTalk. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: BizTalk is a good product but it's quite expensive, can be tedious to deploy and administrate, and is probably not practical for one application unless that application does something to significantly increase revenue for your organization.

Comment: We are a small company, but the product in question will be a product or service we will sell to our clients. We have a desktop application now, and this whole project is to make an easier-to-use web application that anyone from our clients can access and use. It will likely be an alternative to clients that want it, not a replacement to our existing product (though we'd love the majority of them to adopt the web version). It looks like BizTalk does what we need, but I don't think we're willing to invest in it (since most of the functionality has already been built in WCF, though untested).

Comment: You might consider Biztalk being the combination of WCF, WWF, and message persistence.  You might still have a WCF service deployed at each of your client's locations, but let Biztalk at your central site handle all the communication between those remote services and the other systems.  The main reason I brought it up was the robustness that is already built in that you don't have to worry about which can easily eat a ton of a developer's time.